# Value of a variable remains unaltered when assigned during a loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Edit: I'm doing away with pseudocode, here's the actual code. 
I think the answer to question may lie [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323), but I can't understand the answer.

The value of `searchedItem` remains unaltered. The following is my actual code.

```js
const searchedItem = async (req, res) => {
  const { requestedId } = req.query
  const client = await getClient()

  try {
    let searchedItem = 'literallyAnything'

    const allCollections = await db('dbName').listCollections().toArray()

    allCollections.forEach(async (collection) => {
      const allUnits = await client
        .db('dbName')
        .collection(collection.name)
        .find({})
        .toArray()

      for (const topic of allUnits) {
        if (typeof topic === 'object' && Object.keys(topic).length > 1) {
          for (const item in topic) {
            if (typeof topic[item] === 'object') {
              if (topic[item].id == requestedId) {
                searchedItem = await topic[item]
                break
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    })
    res.status(200).json(searchedItem)
  } catch (error) {
    // res.status(500).json(error)
  }
}
```

So, as mentioned above I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323), but I don't understand it.

To tackle the above, I decided to create another method whose sole job would be to send response to the frontend. And I decided to call it from the if statement itself, where I know the value of `searchedItem` still exists, which worked upto an extent. What I mean by that is, I do get the desired output in my browser, but additionally I also get the error `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`, and my server crashes. I'm truncating the code for sake of brevity.

```js
// The new method that I created
const sendResponse = (response, statusCode, data) => response.status(statusCode).json(data)
```

```js
// Including only the modified if statement
if (topic[item].id == requestedId) {
  searchedItem = currentChild
  sendResponse(res, 200, searchedItem)
}
```

What change should I implement in my code?
Thank you.

Comment: That does not look like JavaScript.

Comment: There is no `foreach` keyword in JavaScript. Sure you've got the appropriate tags? Also, in the snippet you've shown `currentChild` and `requestedId` would both be `undefined`, as well as bunch of other stuff.

Comment: yeah this is pseudocode, what I meant was 
```allCollections.foreach(collection => {})```

Comment: Please post actual code, preferably as a [mre] that compiles and showcases the issue you're asking about when one runs it. If you post pseudocode we can't run it to try and reproduce the problem, and if we were to write actual code based on the pseudocode our implementation might be different from yours in ways that matter for the purposes of answering your question.

Comment: `if I do a console.log(searchItem) here I get the desired result` - how? since you `searchedItem = currentChild`, and `searchItem` doesn't seem to be assigned any value anywhere

Comment: @user23901587 Can you explain why you think you can get debugging help or an answer to a technical problem involving language semantics by providing pseudocode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I've replaced pseudocode with the actual code. My bad. I'm sorry guys.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: TLDR; `.forEach` doesn't wait for async callback functions. You can find solutions in the links in my comments. One simple solution is to replace the `.forEach` with a `.map` and await all promises with `Promise.all`. You can find one example in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43766002/16540390

Comment: @Pointy I've now changed the question, mind taking a look?

Comment: Replace `allCollections.forEach(async collection => {` with `for (const collection of asyncCollection) {` (for sequential processing) or `await Promise.all(allCollections.map(async => {` (for parallel processing) and of course close the parentheses accordingly at the end. Problem solved.

Comment: (Duplicate of [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop))

Comment: @CherryDT yeah, didn't know, thanks bro. It worked.